# Why can't JLabel be an inner class declaration

Tags: java

Why cant JLabel in java swing be declared inside the inner class like JMenu or JMenuBar

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class Chk extends JFrame 
{

private JLabel lbl ;

public Chk()
{

lbl = new JLabel("StatusBar");  
lbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
add(lbl,BorderLayout.SOUTH);


JMenuBar menubar=new JMenuBar();
JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
JMenu view = new JMenu("View");

JCheckBoxMenuItem sbar= new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Status-Bar");
sbar.setState(true);
sbar.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{


if (lbl.isVisible())
{lbl.setVisible(false);}
else
{lbl.setVisible(true);}


}});




menubar.add(file);
view.add(sbar);
menubar.add(view);
setJMenuBar(menubar);

setSize(300,200);
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{new Chk();}

}
```

in the above program why do i have to put this line "private JLabel lbl ;"
Why Cant i use JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Label");

Comment: it says "local variable lbl is accessed from inner class , needs  to be declared final"

Comment: So whenever i use a variable in constructor it needs to be 1st declared as private outside ??? or i hav to declare it final , right ???

Comment: It depends if the "variable" has to be reused in all the class. If it's the case, then it must be declared as a field (private, out of a method or the constructor). Moreover if this field has to be used in inner classes (such ActionListener in your case), it must be declared as final.

Comment: thank you Sylvian , your comment cleared lot of my doubts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can**, but variables used in a closure need to be declared final.

```
    final JLabel lbl = new JLabel("StatusBar");
    lbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
    add(lbl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

This should work.

In case you are wondering, the closure is the part where you create an instance of an anonymous inner class and refer to a variable declared in an enclosing scope. In this case 'lbl' is referenced from within an anonymous ActionListener instance:

```
    sbar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (lbl.isVisible()) {
                lbl.setVisible(false);
            } else {
                lbl.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make it private to the constructor because you're attempting to use it outside of the constructor, in the `actionPerformed` method.  You can sneak around that by declaring it final, but I've always thought that was a dubious trick and I don't know if it's guaranteed to work or if it's just fooling the compiler.

Comment: so whenever i use a variable in constructor it needs to be 1st declared as private outside ???

Comment: No, only when you use a variable in a constructor (ctor) that you're then going to use outside the constructor.  If it's declared inside the ctor and not made final, it will vanish as soon as the ctor is finished running.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can, you just need to define it final

you can define it as a local variable before addActionListner.

Comment: If i make it final i wont be able to change its value !!!
also if i want to put it as final where should i do that outside or inside ??

Comment: Why would you change its reference ? The JLabel itself should be the same, but his text can be updated via the setText() method